# Can't access my router in fastapi with postman

Tags: fastapi, router

If I try to access my router(/users/signup)
with postman(send to  http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/signup), it keeps the response "detail": "Not Found"
and fastapi is showing
api   | INFO:     172.19.0.1:43736 - "GET /users/signup HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found

Originally I tried to use post instead of get but it doesn't work anyway

Here is the code in my main.py in the app folder and user.py in the routers folder

main.py:

```
import os
import sys
from .database import init_db
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))))
baseurl = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter
from .routers.user import router as user_router
from .routers.article import router as article_router
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware


router = APIRouter()
router.include_router(user_router, prefix="/users",tags=["users"])
router.include_router(article_router, prefix="/articles",tags=["articles"])
app = FastAPI()
origins = ["http://localhost:3000"]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def on_startup():
    await init_db()
@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message ": " Welcome Fastapi"}

@app.get("/hello/{name}")
async def say_hello(name: str):
    return {"message": f"Hello {name}"}
```

user.py

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

import app.repository.user as dao
from app.admin.utils import currentTime
from app.database import get_db
from app.schemas.user import UserDTO
from app.admin.utils import currentTime

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/signup")
async def signup(user: UserDTO, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    print(f" 회원가입에 진입한 시간: {currentTime()} ")
    print(f"SignUp Inform : {user}")
    result = dao.signup(user, db)
    if result == "":
        result = "failure"
    return {"data": result}


@router.post("/login")
async def login(user: UserDTO, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return_user = dao.login(user, db)
    print(f"로그인 정보 : {return_user}")
    return {"data": return_user}


@router.put("/modify/{id}")
async def update(id: str, item: UserDTO, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    dao.update(id, item, db)
    return {"data": "success"}


@router.delete("/delete/{id}", tags=['age'])
async def delete(id: str, item: UserDTO, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    dao.delete(id, item, db)
    return {"data": "success"}


@router.get("/page/{page}")
async def get_users(page: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    ls = dao.find_users(page, db)
    return {"data": ls}


@router.get("/email/{id}")
async def get_user(id: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    dao.find_user(id, db)
    return {"data": "success"}


@router.get("/point/{search}/{page}")
async def get_users_by_point(search: int, page: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    dao.find_users_by_point(search, page, db)
    return {"data": "success"}
```

What I was expecting is send {"user_email": "hong@naver.com", "id": "hong1234", "username": "홍길동", "password": "hong1234", "cpassword": "hong1234"} by using postman and recieve data:success and enrollment the data to DB

I tried the post method and get method and change router address but it didn't work anyway

Comment: Do other endpoints work?

Comment: only
@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message ": " Welcome Fastapi"}
work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include router in your app too:

```
router = APIRouter()
router.include_router(user_router, prefix="/users",tags=["users"])
router.include_router(article_router, prefix="/articles",tags=["articles"])
app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(router) # Add this.
```

Alternatively remove main router:

```
# Remove router = APIRouter()
app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(user_router, prefix="/users",tags=["users"])
app.include_router(article_router, prefix="/articles",tags=["articles"])
```